# How to read the fuses with avrdude

Tags: atmega, avrdude

I have ea new stk500v2 programmer (Pololu) and want to read the fuses of an atmega8.
With my old programmer I uses the command

```
avrdude -v  -p atmega8 -P /dev/cu.usbmodem002938642 -c stk500v2
```

and got the lfuse and hfuse on 2 lines

Now I only get

```
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9307 (probably m8)
```

Using

```
avrdude -v  -p atmega8 -P /dev/cu.usbmodem002938642 -c stk500v2 -U hfuse:r:-:h
```

I get

```
avrdude: reading hfuse memory:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: writing output file "<stdout>"
0xd9
```

Same with lfuse.
Is there a way to get hfuse and lfuse with the same command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe AVRDUDE allows multiple `-U` options, so try putting this at the end of your command:

```
-U hfuse:r:-:h -U lfuse:r:-:h
```